# Python: count number of days in timestamp over years

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is my `dataframe`. Please note that the last row is from a different year to the previous rows. The index is a datetime.

```
DateTime    data
2016-04-01  14.01
2016-04-02  17.25
2016-04-03  16.99
2016-04-04  17.34
2018-04-05  17.07
```

I want to count the number of unique days in the timestamp.
The following code returns **735**.

```
daily = df.resample('D').sum()
print('Number of days in df:', len(daily.index))
```

I want the result is **5** days.

Comment: You can try df.nunique function over datetime column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `resample` since you aren't doing any kind of operation on the data. You can simply convert the index to `freq='D'` (that's assuming that you need the conversion... that is, that your index might also include timestamps) then count the number of unique values:

```
c.asfreq('D').index.nunique()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) with `%m-%d` for moths with days and add [`Index.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.nunique.html):

```
n = df.index.strftime('%m-%d').nunique()
print('Number of days in df:', n)
#Number of days in df: 5
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
daily = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).sum()
print('Number of days in df:', len(daily.index))
#Number of days in df: 5
```

Or by grouping by separate months and days:

```
daily = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).sum()
print('Number of days in df:', len(daily.index))
#Number of days in df: 5
```

---

But if need number of unique values also with years:

```
n = df.index.nunique()
print('Number of days in df:', n)
#Number of days in df: 5
```